# I am unable to send emails via php using phpmailer and mail function

Tags: php

Perhaps this is not really a programming question and more of a network admin thing, but I am unable to send emails on my server. I started a wordpress blog with a theme that included an email form using the phpmailer class, however it did not work. I tried using a simple mail('asda@example.com','Hey','sdfdsf'); but with no luck.

I've checked my php version and it's 5.1.6, other than that I dont know.

Anyone have some tips?

Comment: Which operation system your site is running on?

Comment: im not sure. I've read that the sendmail_path should be something like /usr/local/nf/bin/sendmail -t -i    however mine has /sbin/  could that be the issue.

Comment: Check phpmailer's `$xxx->ErrorInfo`. If you've configured it to use sendmail and PHPmailer can't find it, it'll be detailed in the ErrorInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't natively support sending email, it hands that duty off to a mail transfer agent.  You also need to have a mail server  (sendmail, postfix, qmail, etc)) installed and configured on your server to actually do the work.  That or there are PHP scripts that'll allow you to send email straight from PHP without a mail server (they just aren't the default ones included in PHP).

A further issue might be that many viruses have propagated through the mail port over the years so many virus scanners and firewalls will prevent access unless they're configured to allow mail to operate.  This is only likely a problem in Windows, and in a network where someone else is looking after the security and assumes the users are dumb (so you know - in the workplace).